# With a multi-type array (with ints and Strings): Using a method, how do I find the smallest int (values given) using a conditional operator?

Tags: java, arrays

I am supposed to create a method to test which if the following int values ( in my multi-value array) is the smallest.

Trying to figure out how to take the int (time) from EACH of my 15 instances in my multi-type array and find the smallest number out of the 15 instances (values given). I would like to use the < operator to test, but I get an error because I cannot use < on Strings, I cant figure out how to specify I only want the time ints when testing.  When I use .getTime in my method, it gives me an error on the return.

Please see bottom of code, "fastestRunner" method -- I get an error on the return as it cannot convert from BanffMarathonRunner(type) to (type)int...

Class extension declaration:

```
public class BanffMarathonRunner extends AddressBook {

    // Initializing fields and their data type:
    private int time;
    private int years;

       //below, fn, ln and homeAddress = from extended AddressBook class

        BanffMarathonRunner[] runners = new BanffMarathonRunner[14];


    public BanffMarathonRunner(String fn, String ln, String homeAddress, int min, int yr) {

         //below "","" ... = method in AddressBook class, voiding other parts of method and only using necessary ones in this program.

        super(fn, "", ln, homeAddress, "", "", "", "", "", "");
        this.time = min;
        this.years = yr;

        runners[0] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);

        runners[0].setFirstName("Elena");
        runners[0].setLastName("Brandon");
        runners[0].setHomeAddress("3076 W 10th Ave, Vancouver, BC, Canada, V5H2K8 ");
        runners[0].setTime(341);
        runners[0].setYears(1);

        runners[1] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);


        runners[1].setFirstName("Thomas");
        runners[1].setLastName("Molson");
        runners[1].setHomeAddress("1926 E 41st Ave, Vancouver, BC, Canada, V9T5Z8 ");
        runners[1].setTime(273);
        runners[1].setYears(2);

        runners[2] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);


        runners[2].setFirstName("Hamilton");
        runners[2].setLastName("Winn");
        runners[2].setHomeAddress("993 Georgia St, Vancouver, BC, Canada, V582G1 ");
        runners[2].setTime(278);
        runners[2].setYears(5);

        runners[3] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);


        runners[3].setFirstName("Suzie");
        runners[3].setLastName("Saradin");
        runners[3].setHomeAddress("89 Fraser St, Vancouver, BC, Canada, V9T3T8 ");
        runners[3].setTime(329);
        runners[3].setYears(7);

        runners[4] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);


        runners[4].setFirstName("Philip");
        runners[4].setLastName("Winne");
        runners[4].setHomeAddress("1896 Sonthon Ave, Calgary, AB, Canada, T2H3A8 ");
        runners[4].setTime(445);
        runners[4].setYears(9);

        runners[5] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);


        runners[5].setFirstName("Alex");
        runners[5].setLastName("Trebok");
        runners[5].setHomeAddress("2891 Creelman Ave, Edmonton, AB, Canada, T6E2A9 ");
        runners[5].setTime(275);
        runners[5].setYears(3);

        runners[6] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);


        runners[6].setFirstName("Emma");
        runners[6].setLastName("Pivoto");
        runners[6].setHomeAddress("976 W 17th Ave, Vancouver, BC, Canada, V6R9A6 ");
        runners[6].setTime(275);
        runners[6].setYears(4);

        runners[7] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);


        runners[7].setFirstName("John");
        runners[7].setLastName("Lenthen");
        runners[7].setHomeAddress("1001 Diskus Ave, Edmonton, AB, Canada, T6E2B1 ");
        runners[7].setTime(243);
        runners[7].setYears(1);

        runners[8] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);


        runners[8].setFirstName("James");
        runners[8].setLastName("Lean");
        runners[8].setHomeAddress("76 Venables St, Vancouver, BC, Canada, V7H2A8 ");
        runners[8].setTime(334);
        runners[8].setYears(1);

        runners[9] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);


        runners[9].setFirstName("Jane");
        runners[9].setLastName("Ostin");
        runners[9].setHomeAddress("1987 E 70th St, Calgary, AB, Canada, T2G4A8 ");
        runners[9].setTime(412);
        runners[9].setYears(1);

        runners[10] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);


        runners[10].setFirstName("Emily");
        runners[10].setLastName("Car");
        runners[10].setHomeAddress("76 W Boulevard, Vancouver, BC, Canada, V6R3H7 ");
        runners[10].setTime(393);
        runners[10].setYears(4);

        runners[11] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);


        runners[11].setFirstName("Daniel");
        runners[11].setLastName("Hamshire");
        runners[11].setHomeAddress("5631 Delna Dr, Calgary, AB, Canada, T2G3A8 ");
        runners[11].setTime(229);
        runners[11].setYears(4);

        runners[12] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);


        runners[12].setFirstName("Neda");
        runners[12].setLastName("Bazdar");
        runners[12].setHomeAddress("1276 Oak St, Calgary, AB, Canada, T2A9A1 ");
        runners[12].setTime(343);
        runners[12].setYears(3);

        runners[13] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);


        runners[13].setFirstName("Aaron");
        runners[13].setLastName("Smith");
        runners[13].setHomeAddress("8706 Greene Dr, Edmonton, AB, Canada, T693B4 ");
        runners[13].setTime(317);
        runners[13].setYears(6);

        runners[14] = new BanffMarathonRunner(fn, ln, homeAddress, min, yr);


        runners[14].setFirstName("Kate");
        runners[14].setLastName("Hen");
        runners[14].setHomeAddress("1912 Benson Ave, Calgary, AB, Canada, T2H7A2 ");
        runners[14].setTime(265);
        runners[14].setYears(8);

    }

    // Getters and setters:

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public int getYears() {
        return years;
    }

    public void setYears(int years) {
        this.years = years;
    }

    // Method to find the fastest runner:
    public static BanffMarathonRunner getFastestRunner(BanffMarathonRunner[] runners) {

        int fastestRunner = runners[0].getTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < runners.length; i++) {
            if (runners[i].getTime() < fastestRunner) {

                fastestRunner = runners[i].getTime();
            //Below is where I have an error saying cannot convert.. 
            **return fastestRunner;**
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getFastestRunner` attempts to return the fastest runner's time, but its return type is `BanffMarathonRunner`. If you wish to return the fastest runner, you should find the index of the fastest runner.

In addition, your return statement should be outside the for loop.

```
public static BanffMarathonRunner getFastestRunner(BanffMarathonRunner[] runners) {    
    int fastestIndex = 0;
    int fastestRunner = runners[0].getTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < runners.length; i++) {
        if (runners[i].getTime() < fastestRunner) {    
            fastestRunner = runners[i].getTime();
            fastestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return runners[fastestIndex];
}
```

P.S. You also have a problem in the initialization of the array in your constructor. You only initialize `runners[0]`, which means your code would throw a `NullPointerException`. And it is wrong to declare and initialize that array in your constructor (since the constructor is calling itself). You should declare and initialize it in your main method.

Comment: Runners array is out of scope, too. It is declared in ctor, locally.

Comment: @Fildor That's also true, but OP didn't show how they plan to call the `getFastestRunner` method, which accepts a `runners` array as an argument.

Comment: Ah. Missed the argument, sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much! I unsure what "Index" means ?

Comment: @Sopieee index means a position in the array.

Comment: @Eran how does it look now that I have initialized all 15 runners?
I also am not sure how to declare the array outside of my constructor so it can be used outside? When I put a } after line  

 BanffMarathonRunner[] runners = new BanffMarathonRunner[14];

I get an error on each line after that.

Comment: @Sopieee Actually, after looking at it more closely, it makes no sense to have the initialization of that array inside the constructor (it will result in infinite recursion, since the constructor is calling itself). Move the declaration and initialization of your array to the main method.

Comment: BanffMarathonRunner[] runners = new BanffMarathonRunner[14];
and
 private int time;
    private int years;

to the main? I just thought that I was suposed to do all of the defining in this class and just call to these methods to print the results from main. 
Sorry, I am learning java.Not very experienced. @Eran

Comment: @Sopieee No. The time and years members should stay in the class. Just move `BanffMarathonRunner[] runners = new BanffMarathonRunner[14];` and all the `runners[i] ...` statements to the main.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type should be an int rather than BanffMarathonRunner if you just wish to return time like:

```
 public static int getFastestRunner(BanffMarathonRunner[] runners) {
```

Comment: Yes, I thought that, but in my assignment instructions it has that declared under operations, so, I think it has to stay as type BanffMarathonRunner... in the past questions for the assignment the operations have remained the same and I built the code based on that. So I am trying to make the method work with that. @SMA